# How packages works in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

How packages works in grails please?
For example if  I have the following structure:

```
org.me.pack1
org.me.pack2  
org.me.pack1.auth  
org.me.pack1.recruitement  
org.me.pack1.recruitement.staff
```

how packages work in this case? are auth,recruitement and staff all included in the same package? can auth package classes call recruitement classes without import?
Thank you

Comment: No, and no http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_package_names https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/

Comment: Ok thank you, so what's the "recommended" way to structure a grails project? when I was using struts2 for example I used to divide my project into beans, services and dao but this is not applicable here since grails generates the dao/services layer

Comment: I'd do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391773/grails-package-structure